# hide attachment from view page and edit page sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I am trying to hide OOTB attachment from listviewform and edit form in my SharePoint 2013 list . I used sharepoint manager tool 2013 to hide it . its working fine for other fields for me like title, body etc but for this attachment the changes are not getting reflected . is there something wrong with the tool , if you guys know any other way around for this .and i dont want to use javascript . if you guys know any other tool for this . pls let me know. thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do? Disable attachments for that List? Did you really use SharePoint Manager to customize the View- and EditForm? Or did you use SharePoint Designer?

Comment: see i dont want attachment field to show in the 'displayform.aspx' and 'editform.aspx' , it should only be visible in the 'newform' . and i used SharePoint manager tool not the designer . as sharepoint manager tool has the options to hide or show the list columns in different forms.

Comment: so i hid other fields like 'body' from the displayform using that tool , but when i do the same thing for attachment it still show up

Comment: Attachment is kind of 'special'.. I never tried hiding fields using SharePoint Manager... Have you tried the option in th UI: Ribbon -> Settings menu -> List Settings -> Advanced settings -> Attachments? There should be an option to (not) add the attachments to default views...

Comment: i dint try that one . let me try

Comment: @Nils no its not there . attachment is not a column so i dont think we can hide it from there

Comment: The button is only available when switching from disabled to enabled. And the button only adds/removes the "attachments" field from the default-view. No changes to the forms..

Comment: @Nils i  dint get you

Answer (score 0):

I see the following options:

1. Use [JavaScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/10063/7045) in the Edit-/DisplayForm to hide the button.
2. A [CustomAction](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/10064/7045) to remove the Button Completely, then add a new one which only appears in the NewForm. (Also JavaScript in this soltution)
3. Add c[ustom Edit- & DisplayForms](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-list-form-using-SharePoint-Designer-917d8fdb-ee00-4441-adb3-a94612d1d105) (not sure if this works, tough)
4. Develop & depoly a WebPart, use [SPRibbon.TrimById](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spribbon.trimbyid.aspx) to remove the attachments-button from the ribbon, add the WebPart to the Edit-&DisplayForm

Answer (score 0):

well i had to do it through css on displayform
`#idAttachmentsRow{display:none !important;}`
                                                   as no other options was there for me and my EditForm was custom so i just kicked that attachment field from it.